# Is it possible to specify the response content inside a IHttpActionResult response to be strongly typed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

It seems with WebAPI 2, your action method's content can be returned in any form.

For example, this GET method works.

```
// GET api/values
public IHttpActionResult Get(bool returnCarViewModel= true)
{
    if (returnCarViewModel)
        return Ok(new CarViewModel());
    else
        return Ok(new AnimalViewModel());

}
```

That seems like bad practice as now the caller must look inside the content of the method to see what type of object I'll be returning and even then, I can return different classes based on the logic I apply inside it.

Is it possible to declare at compile time what the return type I should expect? Something  like...

```
public IHttpActionResult<CarViewModel> Get(bool returnCarViewModel= true)
```

I understand I can simply specify the return type to be CarViewModel but then I'll not be able to take advantage of the abstraction that IHttpActionResult offers

Comment: This would be a terrible API design if you could call the same endpoint and receive different data sets.  Data responses should be idempotent.  You should create two different endpoints.

Comment: @DavidL - yeah exactly. But as it stands, you can definitely do that intentionally or accidentally and the front end dev would need to look inside the action method to figure out what type it'll return

Comment: That is absolutely true.  You can avoid that by returning concrete objects themselves instead of using the abstraction or you can put process gates in place to ensure the quality of your code.  I'd be interested to see how Swagger/Swashbuckler would deal with this kind of api definition.